# Is it possible to set dotnet watch run to replace changed DLLs without restarting the whole process?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am developing ASP.NET Core 3.1 REST API and I use `dotnet watch run`.
This enables me to do fast iteration in development: change .cs file -> rebuild project -> restart the app process -> execute HTTP client request to see the result.

However, this is still slow development workflow (eg. as compared to nodeJS web api devlopment where changes to js file on the server are almost immediately available to http client). It seems to me that the main bottleneck in .NET watch is the process stopping and then starting it again.

Is it possible in ASP.NET Core to somehow make watcher faster (eg. just build the necessary files like one dll and copy it over the old one in output folder without restarting the whole application)?
This would greatly improve development workflow, especially when I want to add integration tests (eg. third party http client that tests my backend and DB) that would run automatically on file changes too.

Comment: The application has to restart to pick up the changes to the referenced DLL(s).

Comment: That would be a really bad idea, if any dll needed any kind of initialization and the process weren't fully restarted it would fail miserably. The best that can be done is edit and continue (that you alread can do): pause the process, allow in-memory editing of safe blocks, apply changes and continue.